# the jquery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

Hi I am using signalR with ASP.Net webforms. For ordinary page its working fine. But for master page inherited page, in the line

```
var chatHub = $.connection.clientUpdateHub;
```

`$.connection` is undefined. The point is, When I see the `$` , its showing that "the jquery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'" I can not understand this. please help me how to avoid this.

Comment: You mean when you `console.log($)` that's the string being output?

Comment: Sounds like _jQuery_ is being vandalised by some other piece of code on your page.

Comment: No it is the tool tip corresponding to $ symbol on visual studio 2012. Normally it will be some function.

Comment: maybe I added reference for both 'jquery-1.6.4.min.js' and 'jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js' js files. But its working with normal web form. But with master page inherited web form it coming like this.

Comment: are you referencing `<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>`? You may need to make the src `/yourAppName/signalr/hubs` if you're using IIS

Comment: yes I referenced <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script> too.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I added  jquery reference like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

in master page and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js") %>"></script>
```

in content pace. So it causes the problem. After removing jquery reference in script manager it works fine for me.